# Struct initialization in C89

Tags: c

I can only initialize the second element of this array of structs. I can't use c99 features like *designated initializers*, so how do i initialize the 0-th element of this array of structs?

```
static uint8_t HEAP_P[32];

struct free_entry
{
    uint8_t *ptr;
    uint64_t size;  
};

typedef struct free_entry free_entry_t;

static free_entry_t free_list[32] = 
{
    {HEAP_P, 64}, //i need to initialize 0-th element to: {ptr = HEAP_P, size = 32}
};
```

ERROR: free_entry is undefined.

But when i do this:

```
static free_entry_t free_list[32] = 
    {
        {0},
        {HEAP_P, 64}, 
    };
```

then everything is working, except i need to initialize the 0-th element, not 1-th.

Comment: Please try to type the code without typos.

Comment: in the first example the structure tag is clearly `struct free_entry`. So why would you expect `static entry_list free_entry[32] = ` to work *at all* ? if anything that should be `static struct free_entry entry_list[32] = `. For future reference, the best way to *not* introduce typos when typing in code is to *not type the code* in the first place. Copy/paste the *real* code from a *real* [mcve] and it removes all doubt.

Comment: @WhozCraig eddited. What about the actual question now?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, no types now.

Comment: Why do you think the first code, with just the `{HEAP_P, 64}` in the initializer, does not initialize the array element with index 0? Did the compiler give an error message? Did your program not behave correctly? Show a [mcve] that demonstrates, possibly using output from the program, that the element with index 1 was initialized and the element with index 0 was not.

Comment: Aside: Is the `size` member supposed to be the size of the buffer pointed to by `ptr`? In the code posted above `ptr` is initialized to point to a 32-byte buffer, but `size` is initialized to 64 for some reason.

Comment: @Tracy Why are you rewriting the provided code instantly? I am sure the question shall be closed. Next time try to provide a minimal complete program without numerous typos.

Answer (score 4):

This typedef is incorrect

```
typedef free_entry free_entry_t;
```

You have to write

```
typedef struct free_entry free_entry_t;
```

I think it is the reason of the error.

This code is compiled successfully

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint8_t HEAP_P[32];

struct free_entry
{
    uint8_t *ptr;
    uint64_t size;  
};

typedef struct free_entry free_entry_t;

static free_entry_t free_list[32] = 
{
    {HEAP_P, 64}, //i need to initialize 0-th element to: {ptr = HEAP_P, size = 32}
};

int main(void) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tested. Nope. MSVC2015.

Comment: @Tracy What do you mean by "Nope." That is not a helpful error description.

Comment: @Tracy Then you'll need to give us the command you're using to compile. This code is compiling for me on both GCC v7.1.0 and MSVC v19.16.27031.1.